# c*(log 2n) is the same as c + c*log n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I am reading a chapter of my data structures book that is about big O notation and have come across an example where I do not understand the Algebra behind it:

" On the other hand, if a search algorithm is O(log n) and you double the size of the collection, you go from c*(log n) to c*(log 2n), which is simply c + c*log n."

How is c*(log 2n) the same as c + c*log n ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$c\log(2n) = c(\log2+\log n) = c\log2 + c\log n$$
Note that the first term is constant

Comment: Very, very interesting.  So you are saying that because c log 2 would result in a constant, then we can simply represent it as c, which would mean that c log(2n) can indeed be represented as: c +c log n.  Nice!  Thanks!

Comment: @timbram exactly! As Clive mentioned in his posts this is a little informal, and *should* be left as I leave it to be *precise*. However, for large $n$ any constant is tiny, so the loss in information is small

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ refers to a fixed consonant, then
$$c\log(2n) = c(\log 2 + \log n) = c\log 2 + c\log n$$
and not $c + c\log n$. However, $c\log 2$ is constant with respect to $n$, so what is written may have been informal notation in which each instance of the variable $c$ refers to a (possibly different) quantity which is constant with respect to $n$.